# Capturing non-type template parameter in lambda expression

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, c++17

Why it's forbidden to capture non-type template parameters in the lambda capture list?

The following code fails to compile on both GCC and clang:

```
template<int x>
auto foo()
{
    return [x]{return x;};
}
```

with an error message `capture of non-variable 'x'` on GCC and `'x' in capture list does not name a variable` on clang.

... however, the following code compiles fine:

```
template<int x>
auto bar()
{
    return [y = x]{return y;};
}
```

Comment: example: https://godbolt.org/z/3s1dhEzvv

Comment: `x` is compile time constant you do not have to capture it. It is like trying capture a global - there is no point. https://godbolt.org/z/zax4z35o3

Comment: For pretty much the same reason that the capture list `[2]` is bad, but `[y=2]` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot capture them because you don't *need* to. Template parameters of the enclosing function/class of a lambda are accessible to the lambda. Just like template parameters of a class template are accessible to any member function of that class template.

Comment: Additional though: what would mean `[&x]{return x;}` if capturing `x` would be possible?